# How to add event attribute to html tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I created some label tag with JavaScript something like this:

```
 var labelTag = document.createElement("label"); 
 labelTag.id = i; 
 labelTag.className ="myrows"; 
 labelTag.innerHTML = data[1];
```

It's ok, but I need to add onlick attribute to this label too.

So I need to look the result something like this:

```
  <label id='0' class='myrows' onclick=myfunction('first','second',..)> some info here</label>
```

I try with this: `labelTag.onclick=myfunction('first',second,...);`

No code error, but after I run the page on browser and see the source this attribute is missing. What's wrong?

Comment: can we try with jQuery??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var labelTag = document.createElement("label"); 
labelTag.id = i; 
labelTag.className ="myrows"; 
labelTag.innerHTML = data[1];
labelTag.onclick = function() {
   alert('Clicked');
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This

```
labelTag.onclick = myfunction('first', 'second', ...);
```

assigns the **return value** of `myfunction` to `labelTag.onclick`.

You have to wrap it into an anonymous function if you want to pass parameters to the function:

```
labelTag.onclick = function() {
    myfunction('first', 'second', ...);
};
```

Note that you won't see any changes in the DOM if you inspect it.

---

For more information about event handling and the various ways to attach handlers, I recommend to read the [excellent articles on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

Comment: ehh...i tought it shown in the source, your comment is work well too, but that was the second one..so...thank you Master

Comment: @holian: *i tought it shown in the source* I don't know that you mean with that. *that was the second one* And what do you mean with that?